# Opamp isolation resistor calculations for a capacitive load

Tags: amplifier, capacitance, stability

I want to add a capacitive filter for pulse shaping to the output of a transimpedance amplifier using an OPA847.  Without the filter, the amplifier works great.  With the filter, I get some oscillation because the filter presents a ~40pF capacitance to the TIA output.

The OPA847 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa847.pdf) recommends using a series isolation resistor to separate the capacitive load from the feedback circuit:

[image: Driving capacitive loads]

They give recommended values for a 20 V/V gain, and further state:

> The criterion for setting the RS resistor is a maximum bandwidth, flat frequency response at the load. For the OPA847
>   operating in a gain of +20, the frequency response at the
>   output pin is very flat to begin with, allowing relatively small
>   values of RS to be used for low capacitive loads. As the signal
>   gain is increased, the unloaded phase margin also increases.
>   Driving capacitive loads at higher gains requires lower RS
>   values than those shown for a gain of +20.

This is indeed the case, if I use the recommended 30 ohms (for 20V/V) in my transimpedance amplifier, the oscillation is hardly damped.  I could just keep trying larger values until it works, but I'd like to understand how that value of 30 ohms is calculated, and how it would be calculated in the case of transimpedance amplifier which has transimpedance gain rather than voltage gain.  This is probably obvious, but I'm missing something.

Edit:  Here is a diagram of the the transimpedance amplifier and with a capacitive load:

[image]

Comment: What kind of pulse shaping are you trying to do? If the TIA circuit were ideal, placing a capacitance directly on its output would not provide any pulse shaping, so I'm not clear why you are starting there, and then trying to improve the ringing. Have you considered a capacitor in parallel with your feedback resistor? That will provide one zero and one pole in the TIA response, which may also provide the pulse shaping you're looking for (for example, if your main goal is to limit the output rise and fall times)

Comment: It would probably be helpful to share your actual circuit schematic. The only schematic you've included in your post so far does not show a TIA configuration, so I assume it is not the circuit you're working with.

Comment: From p. 11 in the datasheet you linked there is discussion of how to design a TIA with this op-amp. They tell you how to choose \$C_f\$ for maximum bandwidth. Increasing \$C_f\$ above their recommendation will reduce the bandwidth (possibly providing the pulse shaping you want) but normally not have any other negative consequence. (Decreasing \$C_f\$ can lead to ringing)

Comment: @ThePhoton The amplifier itself is already compensated with a feedback capacitor, and has a near-ideal frequency response.  The pulse shaping is for the detector, which has a complex, multi-exponential output.   I put the pulse shaping after the amplifier since it would be hard to put it on the input side of the transimpedance amplifier.

I'll edit with a picture of the transimpedance amplifier, but it is nothing special.

Comment: OK what I'm saying is, consider if changing the feedback capacitor value, or adding another RC branch in the feedback path, could give you the pulse shaping you want.  Then you wouldn't have any problem with capacitively loading your op-amp.

Comment: That is an interesting idea for the future, but I'd like to understand the more general process of compensating opamps for capacitive loads in any case.  Any ideas?

Comment: The schematic you show IS NOT the same as the datasheet diagram. You show the capacitance within the feedback loop. It should not be. The datasheet clearly shows the filter capacitance is grounded, and isolated by Rs.

Comment: @JackCreasey The capacitance in the feedback loop because this is a transimpedance amplifier.  I am asking, given a transimpedance design (or any design for that matter), how is the isolation resistor value actually calculated?